# Roslyn, CSharpCompilation detail info

Tags: c#, roslyn

This is my code example

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RoslynTest
{ 
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                myClass obj = new myClass();
                obj.Exec();
            }
        }
    
        public class myClass
        {
    
            private string _path;
            private readonly IEnumerable<MetadataReference> DefaultReferences =
                new[]
                {
    
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\mscorlib.dll"),
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.dll"),
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Core.dll")
                };
    
            private readonly CSharpCompilationOptions DefaultCompilationOptions =
                new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
                        .WithOverflowChecks(true).WithOptimizationLevel(OptimizationLevel.Release)
                        .WithUsings(new[]
                {
                    "System",
                    "System.Collections.Generic"
                });
    
            private SyntaxTree Parse(string text, string filename = "", CSharpParseOptions options = null)
            {
                var stringText = SourceText.From(text, Encoding.UTF8);
                return SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(stringText, options, filename);
            }
    
            private string source = "public class Test1 { public int Amount {get; set;}   public void CalcAmo() { Amount = Amount + 500;} public void CalcAmo1() { Amount = Amount + 1000;  } } ";
    
            public void Exec()
            {
                var parsedSyntaxTree = Parse(source, "", CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithLanguageVersion(LanguageVersion.CSharp6));
                var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                                    "Compilation",
                                    syntaxTrees: new SyntaxTree[] { parsedSyntaxTree },
                                    references: DefaultReferences,
                                    options: DefaultCompilationOptions);
                _path = "C:\\custom.dll";
                var result = compilation.Emit(_path);
                if (!result.Success)
                {
                    foreach (var item in result.Diagnostics)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                    }
                    }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
}
```

I am creating compilation by input string then getting compilation errors from diagnostics, but it is not enough

I want to know everything about compilation error.

1. in which line from my class is there an error? (line in class)
2. in which method/property there is an error?
3. in which line from method/property there is an error? (line in method)
4. error message, warning...

in this code there is not any compilation error, but if it there will be I would to get detailed information about error, for example if I will remove some '**;**' from input string I will get "**; expected**", but it is not enough. I would get detail information, for example in which line is this error?

it is possible? please help me.

Thank in advance

Comment: Now i dont get any error, but i want to get error detail info4mation if it will be exist, it is example how i am compiling, in real project, i will have big class with many methods and properties, and it will be compile runtime, and i need to get error detail information if there is an error

Comment: I want to get error from runtime compilatiin by string, try/catch?))) it is runtime compilation, i want to get compilation error)

Comment: Did you look at the properties in `item`?

Comment: i will explore and will answer

Comment: I have found some methods in Diagnostic.Location property (GetLineSpan().StartLinePosition,  GetLineSpan().EndLinePosition) which have helped me

Answer (score 0):

I have found some methods in Diagnostic.Location property `(GetLineSpan().StartLinePosition,  GetLineSpan().EndLinePosition)` which have helped me